# What packages do i have to download to make unity interact with hololens in order to detect and get positions of my hand?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, package, hololens, interaction

i have a code written on visual studio 2017 and put into unity 2018 scripts that allows me to get the position of my hand with hololens glasses through Interaction Manager and its events. But my issue is: what package(s) should i import into the unity scene (unity 2018.4.17) in order to make the whole work and to make hololens glasses really interact with my hand when it is in its field of view ? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefore, what you really want is an SDK with an implementation of hand interaction, so that you can invoke that function directly to implement your ideas?

If so, [MRTKv2](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/README.html) be always recommended for accelerating cross-platform MR app development in Unity. It provides a set of components and features including [Hand tracking](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/HandTracking.html),[Interactable](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.4.0/Documentation/README_Interactable.html),[Object manipulator](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.4.0/Documentation/README_ObjectManipulator.html). Besides, if you're new to MRTK or Mixed Reality development in Unity, we recommend you start at the beginning of our [Unity development journey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-development-overview?tabs=mrtk%2Carr%2Chl2) in the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thank you very much